# SwiftUI "Push" NavigationView/NavigationLink not working when trying to create multi-screen flow

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI, I set up a 4 screen flow (1>2>3>4) where the user would hit "next" on each to navigate to the next screen - just like a typical push flow in UIKit.  Im using "programmatic" `NavigationLink`s (e.g. `isActive` parameter) for flexibility. It gets to screen 3, but for some reason hitting next on screen 3 doesn't navigate to screen 4.  Can't figure it out.

```
struct FlowView: View {
@State var navigateToScreen2 = false
@State var navigateToScreen3 = false
@State var navigateToScreen4 = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Text("Screen 1")
            Button(action: { self.navigateToScreen2 = true }, label: { Text("Next") })
            NavigationLink(destination:
                VStack {
                    Text("Screen 2")
                    Button(action: { self.navigateToScreen3 = true }, label: { Text("Next") })
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                       VStack {
                            Text("Screen 3")
                            Button(action: { self.navigateToScreen4 = true}, label: { Text("Next") })
                            NavigationLink(destination:
                                Text("Screen 4"),
                                isActive: self.$navigateToScreen4,
                                label: { EmptyView() }
                            )
                        },
                        isActive: self.$navigateToScreen3,
                        label: { EmptyView() }
                    )
                },
                isActive: self.$navigateToScreen2,
                label: { EmptyView() }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this. It works and can be much better read:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var navigateToScreen2 = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: View2(), isActive: $navigateToScreen2) {
                Text("View1")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @State private var navigateToScreen3 = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: View3(), isActive: $navigateToScreen3) {
            Text("View2")
        }
    }
}

struct View3: View {
    @State private var navigateToScreen4 = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: View4(), isActive: $navigateToScreen4) {
            Text("View3")
        }
    }
}

struct View4: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View4")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!  Yes it definitely reads better, but was trying to keep the navigation state outside of the individual views (the example code is simply a way of demonstrating the problem).  My goal is to have screen views that do not know anything about how they fit into navigation and have an overall view controlling navigation.  Will play with this idea though thank you.  The question I have is why doesn't the code work?

Comment: A NavigationLink is not well placed inside a Button. You double trigger the state with your Button-Action + dual binding of the NavigationLink. When you switch too often between your Views you will also see strange behavior like suddenly jumping back and forth between Views.

Comment: NavigationLink isn't inside a Button - not sure I follow.

Comment: NavigationLink gets executed when tapping the Button. That is what I meant with "inside a Button". I think all this is enough answer for one question. This is not a chat platform. :-)